# How to load platform specific fonts at runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, cross-platform

I am trying to make the app sets some of the assets based on platform.

First step is to have the font based on OS, Roboto for Android and SanFrancisco for iOS.

Simply said, Unity cannot import font at runtime, quite a bit of a drawback compared to any other cross-platform IDE but we not here to judge. The other solution is to use AssetBundle which for unexplanable reasons fails top work for me...

On top of that, it is not widely conceived to store basic assets like font as something else than font.

So my final solution is this ugly script:

```cs
class FontFamily
{
     [Header("Android")]
     [SerializeField]
     private Font regularAndroid = null;
     [SerializeField]
     private Font boldAndroid = null;
     [SerializeField]
     private Font italicAndroid = null;
     [Header("iOS")]
     [SerializeField]
     private Font regularIOS = null;
     [SerializeField]
     private Font boldIOS = null;
     [SerializeField]
     private Font italicIOS = null;
     public Font Regular
     {
         get
         {
 #if UNITY_ANDROID
             return this.regularAndroid;
 #elif UNITY_IOS
             return this.regularIOS;
 #endif
         }
     }
     public Font Bold
     {
         get
         {
 #if UNITY_ANDROID
             return this.boldAndroid;
 #elif UNITY_IOS
             return this.boldIOS;
 #endif
         }
     }
     public Font Italic
     {
         get
         {
 #if UNITY_ANDROID
             return this.italicAndroid;
 #elif UNITY_IOS
             return this.italicIOS;
 #endif
         }
     }
 }
```

Just looking for a way to improve that, coz in the long run this is not a viable solution. I can't even have the macros on the references as they get lost while switching.

I was thinking of some prebuild script maybe, basically, how do you do that?

Comment: *" The other solution is to use AssetBundle which for unexplanable reasons fails top work for me..."* How about the Resources folder?

Comment: That would defeat the idea of not loading useless assets. The whole point is to ship a build for Android containing only android assets and same for iOS. Resources would build the whole content.

Comment: I would have hoped to be able to download ttf from a url but Unity does not support runtime loading of font...this is where I tried AB but not working and I would expect a way that does not require a dependency to Unity.

Comment: Really interesting issue and I think there is a better solution.. I will dig more into this when I return to my working PC

Comment: One old answer on Unity Forum from what used to be a Unity employee was to use AB, which turns out to be a working solution (if I could get it to work) but there has to be a more versatile solution complying with the cross-platform concept widely used in Xamarin or web design. I would love to see Unity developing UI more natively so non-game apps could take advantage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, Unity can import fonts at runtime without using ABs, but only OS's fonts, by using `Font.CreateDynamicFontFromOSFont`.

Very simple script that load the Roboto font in Android and San Francisco in iOS:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class LoadFontFromOS : MonoBehaviour {

    const string ANDROID_FONT_NAME = "Roboto";
    const string IOS_FONT_NAME = "SanFrancisco";

    string[] OSFonts;
    static Font selectedFont;
    public static Font SelectedFont {
        get {
            return selectedFont;
        }
    }
    static bool isFontFound;
    public static bool IsFontFound {
        get {
            return isFontFound;
        }
    }

    private void Awake() {
        isFontFound = false;
        OSFonts = Font.GetOSInstalledFontNames();
        foreach (var font in OSFonts) {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
            if (font == ANDROID_FONT_NAME) {
                selectedFont = Font.CreateDynamicFontFromOSFont(ANDROID_FONT_NAME, 1);
                isFontFound = true;
            }
#elif UNITY_IOS
            if (font == IOS_FONT_NAME) {
                selectedFont = Font.CreateDynamicFontFromOSFont(IOS_FONT_NAME, 1);
                isFontFound = true;
            }
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

You can then change the font of all `Text` types with a simple

```cs
text.font = LoadFontFromOS.IsFontFound ? LoadFontFromOS.SelectedFont : text.font;
```

where needed.

I tested it on Android and it works, I don't have an iOS device to test it but it should work the same.

Comment: That does actually work on Android. Thanks a lot. It's simple and straightforward. I'll check on iOS to confirm but there is little to no reason why it should no work. Thanks again.

Comment: One thing I just noticed: it's better to add a `bool` to check if the specific font you want to load is present in the array, since if you try to load a font with a name that doesn't exist, Unity doesn't throw any exception, and you'll end up with text that isn't rendered. I'll edit my script to add this.

Comment: I've changed the `size` argument to 1, apparently nothing changes when varying the value (tested with 1 and 10000, same font size). I have no clue why this happens.

Comment: That’d be the default size which is overridden by the text size. I would assume a larger size would give a sharper result as it happens when u increase the size in the font importer but u seem to say that it does not.

Comment: I thought the same, but if you try to pass 0 as the size, then the font is rendered with the same size (driven by `text.size` I mean), but shifted up (just the bottom of the text is rendered inside the rect of the UI element).

Comment: There's a minor typo in your script under the IOS directive; `Font.CreateDynamicFontFromOSFont(ANDROID_FONT_NAME, 1);` should probably be `Font.CreateDynamicFontFromOSFont(IOS_FONT_NAME, 1);`  :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be working for me (Unity 2019.1.0f2, iOS 12.2). The script itself works fine, but neither "SanFrancisco" or any other variant such as "San Francisco" or "SF" is in the list of font names returned from `Font.GetOSInstalledFontNames()`. Has anyone gotten this working with San Francisco on iOS?

Comment: I can confirm that this works fine for Android. iOS though hasn´t the San Francisco font in the list, as mentioned by @PaulStraw.

Comment: @PaulStraw @railon Maybe a little late but the font path and font file name are `/System/Library/Fonts/CoreUI/SFUI.ttf` and `System Font` respectively.